# Remove selected component from combobox DELPHI

Tags: delphi, combobox

I have ComboBox4,ComboBox1 and Button5
When I click Button5 program should remove component selected in combobox4 from the ComboBox4 and ComboBox1 components' list. But I get list out of bounds error with the following code...

```
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
cat : Integer;
trinti: TComponent;
catT : String;
begin
catT := ComboBox4.Text;
cat := ComboBox4.Items.IndexOf(catT);
trinti := ComboBox4.Components[cat];

ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
ComboBox4.Items.BeginUpdate;
  ComboBox4.RemoveComponent(trinti);
  ComboBox1.RemoveComponent(trinti);
ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
ComboBox4.Items.EndUpdate;

removeCat(catT);
end;
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Components` property, and the `RemoveComponent` method are the wrong things to use here. These are for ownership and lifetime management. Typically the only thing on your form that owns anything is the form itself. So using `Components` on the combo box will always results in an error.

Instead you need to use the `Items` property of the combo box, and its `Delete` method. It might look like this:

```
var
  Index: Integer;
....
catT := ComboBox4.Text;
Index := ComboBox4.Items.IndexOf(catT);
if Index <> -1 then
  ComboBox4.Items.Delete(Index);
```

Comment: Like this: ComboBox4.Items[cat].Delete;? But there is not delete method for Items[]. :/

Comment: I see, but i still get list out of bounds somewhy, see my code: http://pastebin.com/ruNcU4yf

Comment: You aren't heeding my advice. Read the first paragraph of my answer again. Then ask yourself what `trinti := ComboBox4.Components[cat]` does.

Comment: I don't want to create new topic, so maybe you also know how to run a procedure not by user, but immediately when program starts, I want to load my XML and add info from xml to my comboboxes when program starts.

Comment: Attach a method to the form's `OnCreate` event to perform initialisation.

Comment: mmm, like 
procedure Tform1.onCreate.Dosomething;
?

Comment: Not really. Perhaps you should back track a little and do the Delphi intro tutorial again. Learn about how to assign event handlers to events.